# Redis takes long to load data sometimes

Tags: node.js, express, redis

I am using redis to cache user credentials and it takes too long. normally without cache it takes no longer than 80ms (most timing is equal to 5-20ms) but with cache it takes 3XXms. here is my code

```
    const hashGetAll = promisify(cache.hgetall).bind(cache);
    const userData = await hashGetAll(req.userId);
    if(userData){
        return res.status(200).send({
            user: userData
        })
    }
    //User Query
    const stringCredentials = JSON.stringify(credentials)
    cache.hset(req.userId, stringCredentials);
    return res.status(200).send({user: credentials})
```

Answer (score 0):

**hashGetAll** has time complexity of O(n) . So , If the userData has more data , it takes more time . if possible use **hget** .